# WPF Visual Preview hangs indefinitely

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, data-binding, designer

I've been developing a WPF interface for the past year, and this week I've noticed I can no longer open the interface within Visual Studio 2010 without it hanging indefinitely.  I'm wondering why this has just started happening.  I've checked through the SQL settings for the data bindings and everything seems fine.  Does anyone know of any of other options I have?  I can't seem to cancel this endless loading.

[image]

Comment: did you recently install any service packs or extensions to visual studio 2010?

Comment: Only Visual Studio 2010 SP1 a while back, although also uninstalled Resharper as well.

Comment: Which extensions are installed? I am occasionally experiencing the same problem. Maybe we can figure it out.

Comment: Only one extension AnkhSVN was installed, which I have now removed.  Note that other XAML windows open of the same project, it's just one that fails to load.

Comment: @wonea - Try removing controls from the window until it loads. There may be some designer code for one of the controls that is causing the problem.

Comment: @CodeNaked Cheers, it's a massive window, I'll try, gonna be quite a big task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution.  One of my datagrids was attached to a DataSet which return a list of log records.  Now as the system went through testing the long grew, making the sql query take longer and longer to return.  I noticed this by running the JetBrains dotTrace tool on the application, and profiled the startup sequence, this identified the SQL query which was causing the delay.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have tired to reboot?  For me sometimes a compile that usually takes 10 seconds will take minutes.  I reboot and it works fine for a couple days or a couple hours.  SP1 helped.